# Laplace transform with Heaviside Unit step function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Working on a question and was wondering if this is right.

Find the Laplace transform:

$$x'' + 2x' + x = f(t)$$ $$x(0)=x'(0)=0$$
$$f(t) = \begin{cases}2 ,& 0 \leq t \leq 2 \\t ,& t \ge 2\end{cases}$$

Heaviside function: $$2-tu(t-2)$$

The Laplace transform of it is : $$\frac{2}{s} -\frac{1}{s^3}e^{-2s}$$

Then, let $$X = \mathcal{L}{x(t)}$$
$$\mathcal{L}x'' = s^2X - sx(0) - x'(0) = {s^2}X$$
$$\mathcal{L}x' = 2(sX-x(0))= 2sX$$

The transformed equation would be:
$$s^2X +2sX + X = \frac{2}{s} - \frac{e^2s}{s^3} => X = \frac{2}{s(s+1)^2} - \frac{e^-2s}{s^3(s+1)^2}$$

Now, to solve for x(t), I have to use partial fraction right? Or is there a faster way!

Also, I have a question regarding the $$\leq and < $$ signs.
If I had $$0 \leq t < 2$$ instead, what impact does it have on the equation.

---

Would someone want to guide me through the convolution? I'm not exactly sure where to start.

Comment: The other option would be using of convolution I guess. The swaping of $ne$ and $<$ wouldn't change anything here.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky Ah, convolution... yes! Would there be other situations that $$\leq and <$$ would mean something?

Comment: start from reading about convolution http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ConvolutionIntegrals.aspx